# How to get mime type of an array buffer object?

Tags: javascript, angular, file-upload, blob, arraybuffer

I am working on an API which is fetching file data as `arraybuffer` type. What my main question is there any of knowing what is the mime type of the file from the `arraybuffer` as I need to convert it to `BLOB` to view the file.

```
var file1 = new Blob([response], { type: file.type });
var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file1);
```

In the above code snippet, the `response` is an `arraybuffer` and the mime type I got is by storing it while uploading in a variable. But now the scenario is I don't have any mime type in my hand so I need a way to get it.

This is my response header:
[image: header]

And this is my response body sample:
[image: body]

Can anyone suggest me anything ?

Comment: Couldn't you get it from the response headers?

Comment: @AndreiGătej please refer my updated question. I am not getting any mime type in response header

Answer (score 4):

Alternative to `file-type` which seems to also use magic signature :

```
function getMimeTypeFromArrayBuffer(arrayBuffer) {
  const uint8arr = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)

  const len = 4
  if (uint8arr.length >= len) {
    let signatureArr = new Array(len)
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++)
      signatureArr[i] = (new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer))[i].toString(16)
    const signature = signatureArr.join('').toUpperCase()

    switch (signature) {
      case '89504E47':
        return 'image/png'
      case '47494638':
        return 'image/gif'
      case '25504446':
        return 'application/pdf'
      case 'FFD8FFDB':
      case 'FFD8FFE0':
        return 'image/jpeg'
      case '504B0304':
        return 'application/zip'
      default:
        return null
    }
  }
  return null
}
```

inspired from https://medium.com/the-everyday-developer/detect-file-mime-type-using-magic-numbers-and-javascript-16bc513d4e1e

Comment: More specifically, `signatureArr[i] = (new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer))[i].toString(16)` should be replaced with `signatureArr[i] = (new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer))[i].toString(16).padStart(2, "0")`. Moreover, it's recommended to use the signature database: [https://gist.github.com/Qti3e/6341245314bf3513abb080677cd1c93b](https://gist.github.com/Qti3e/6341245314bf3513abb080677cd1c93b)

Answer (score 3):

I found this package below which is very interesting. It parses the array buffer/blob/stream and try to guess its extension and mime type if it were a file. Obviously it is not exhaustive but you can find the extension list in the readme. Works on node and browser. Works for my needs though.

Here is the repo link : https://github.com/sindresorhus/file-type